# Terraform keeps deleting and creating attached_disk associations in an endless loop

Tags: google-cloud-platform, terraform, storage

So, I stumbled upon some funky behavior...

I do `terraform plan` and it wants to delete 2 disks associations (attached disks) for my VM:

```
- attached_disk {
          - device_name = "persistent-disk-1" -> null
          - mode        = "READ_WRITE" -> null
          - source      = "https://www.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/truthisstranger/zones/us-central1-a/disks/app-truthisstranger-production-010cc51d847b4862-docker" -> null
        }
      - attached_disk {
          - device_name = "persistent-disk-2" -> null
          - mode        = "READ_WRITE" -> null
          - source      = "https://www.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/truthisstranger/zones/us-central1-a/disks/app-truthisstranger-production-010cc51d847b4862-docker-volumes" -> null
        }
```

I'm like, okay... `terraform apply` then, my VM no longer has those disks associated... I do `terraform plan` once more:

```
Terraform will perform the following actions:

  # google_compute_attached_disk.app_server_docker_disk will be created
  + resource "google_compute_attached_disk" "app_server_docker_disk" {
      + device_name = (known after apply)
      + disk        = "projects/truthisstranger/zones/us-central1-a/disks/app-truthisstranger-production-010cc51d847b4862-docker"
      + id          = (known after apply)
      + instance    = "projects/truthisstranger/zones/us-central1-a/instances/app-truthisstranger-production-010cc51d847b4862"
      + mode        = "READ_WRITE"
      + project     = (known after apply)
      + zone        = (known after apply)
    }

  # google_compute_attached_disk.app_server_docker_volume_disk will be created
  + resource "google_compute_attached_disk" "app_server_docker_volume_disk" {
      + device_name = (known after apply)
      + disk        = "projects/truthisstranger/zones/us-central1-a/disks/app-truthisstranger-production-010cc51d847b4862-docker-volumes"
      + id          = (known after apply)
      + instance    = "projects/truthisstranger/zones/us-central1-a/instances/app-truthisstranger-production-010cc51d847b4862"
      + mode        = "READ_WRITE"
      + project     = (known after apply)
      + zone        = (known after apply)
    }

Plan: 2 to add, 0 to change, 0 to destroy.
```

And I'm like... okay, that makes sense although I didn't move anything, I do `terraform apply` once more, my disks are connected to the VM again, but then... without changing any code... `terraform plan`:

```
Terraform will perform the following actions:

  # google_compute_instance.app_server will be updated in-place
  ~ resource "google_compute_instance" "app_server" {
        id                        = "projects/truthisstranger/zones/us-central1-a/instances/app-truthisstranger-production-010cc51d847b4862"
        name                      = "app-truthisstranger-production-010cc51d847b4862"
        tags                      = [
            "http-server",
            "https-server",
        ]
        # (19 unchanged attributes hidden)

      - attached_disk {
          - device_name = "persistent-disk-1" -> null
          - mode        = "READ_WRITE" -> null
          - source      = "https://www.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/truthisstranger/zones/us-central1-a/disks/app-truthisstranger-production-010cc51d847b4862-docker" -> null
        }
      - attached_disk {
          - device_name = "persistent-disk-2" -> null
          - mode        = "READ_WRITE" -> null
          - source      = "https://www.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/truthisstranger/zones/us-central1-a/disks/app-truthisstranger-production-010cc51d847b4862-docker-volumes" -> null
        }




        # (4 unchanged blocks hidden)
    }

Plan: 0 to add, 1 to change, 0 to destroy.
```

So it wants to remove the associations again, no code changes.... what the hell is going on?

P.S.: Here is my terraform code

```
resource "random_id" "instance_id" {
    byte_length = 8
}



// A single Compute Engine instance
resource "google_compute_instance" "app_server" {
    name         = "app-${var.gcp_provider_project}-${var.app_server_environment}-${random_id.instance_id.hex}"
    machine_type = var.app_server_machine_type
    zone         = var.gcp_provider_zone

    allow_stopping_for_update   = true

    boot_disk {
        initialize_params {
            image = var.app_server_image
        }
    }

    // Install Docker from official source
    metadata_startup_script = <<SCRIPT
        sudo apt-get update
        sudo apt-get install -y \
            ca-certificates \
            curl \
            gnupg \
            lsb-release

        curl -fsSL https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu/gpg \
            | sudo gpg --dearmor -o /usr/share/keyrings/docker-archive-keyring.gpg

        echo \
            "deb [arch=$(dpkg --print-architecture) signed-by=/usr/share/keyrings/docker-archive-keyring.gpg] https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu \
            $(lsb_release -cs) stable" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/docker.list > /dev/null

        sudo apt-get update
        sudo apt-get install -y \
            docker-ce \
            docker-ce-cli \
            containerd.io
    SCRIPT

    network_interface {
        network = "default"

        access_config {
            nat_ip = "${google_compute_address.static_ip.address}"
        }
    }

    lifecycle{
        ignore_changes = [
          metadata_startup_script
        ]
    }

    tags = ["http-server","https-server"]
}

//Docker daemon disk association
resource "google_compute_attached_disk" "app_server_docker_disk"{
    disk        = google_compute_disk.docker_disk.id
    instance    = google_compute_instance.app_server.id
}

//Docker volume disk association
resource "google_compute_attached_disk" "app_server_docker_volume_disk"{
    disk        = google_compute_disk.docker_volume_disk.id
    instance    = google_compute_instance.app_server.id
}

//Docker disk
resource "google_compute_disk" "docker_disk" {
    name = "${google_compute_instance.app_server.name}-docker"

    type = var.app_server_docker_disk_type
    size = var.app_server_docker_disk_size
}

//Docker disk
resource "google_compute_disk" "docker_volume_disk" {
    name = "${google_compute_instance.app_server.name}-docker-volumes"

    type = var.app_server_docker_volume_disk_type
    size = var.app_server_docker_volume_disk_size
}
```

Update: This behavior was documented as a bug, but it still doesn't seem right andafter adding the `lifecycle` `ignore_changes` `attached_disks` it seems it will now always display this:

```
Note: Objects have changed outside of Terraform

Terraform detected the following changes made outside of Terraform since the last "terraform apply":

  # google_compute_instance.app_server has changed
  ~ resource "google_compute_instance" "app_server" {
        id                        = "projects/truthisstranger/zones/us-central1-a/instances/app-truthisstranger-production-010cc51d847b4862"
        name                      = "app-truthisstranger-production-010cc51d847b4862"
        tags                      = [
            "http-server",
            "https-server",
        ]
        # (19 unchanged attributes hidden)

      + attached_disk {
          + device_name = "persistent-disk-1"
          + mode        = "READ_WRITE"
          + source      = "https://www.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/truthisstranger/zones/us-central1-a/disks/app-truthisstranger-production-010cc51d847b4862-docker"
        }
      + attached_disk {
          + device_name = "persistent-disk-2"
          + mode        = "READ_WRITE"
          + source      = "https://www.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/truthisstranger/zones/us-central1-a/disks/app-truthisstranger-production-010cc51d847b4862-docker-volumes"
        }




        # (4 unchanged blocks hidden)
    }


Unless you have made equivalent changes to your configuration, or ignored the relevant attributes using ignore_changes, the following plan may include   
actions to undo or respond to these changes.
```

Here is a link to the github issue: https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform-provider-google/issues/2098

Comment: Without seeing your config, it appears that you are attempting to attach these disks to a VM with both nested blocks in the resource and independent resources. These are conflicting API endpoints, and you need to specify only once (preferably the independent resources for robustness). Seeing your config would confirm one way or the other.

Comment: @MattSchuchard I updated the post with my terraform code, is this what you mean by config?

Comment: @MattSchuchard I see what you mean since I went deeper into a previous `tfstate` file which doesn't have `attached_disk` attributes, but the later one does... however, as you can see, I never declared any attached disks within the `compute_instance` block. It didn't use to do this, I had added the disks several versions of my infrastructure ago.

Comment: @MattSchuchard I even tried deleting one of them with `terraform state rm` and reimporting it with `terraform import`, as well as modifying the `tfstate` file manually to remove those `attached_disk` blocks from the instance block. Like I mentioned, I never declared `attached_disk` within the instance, my code has never changed from what you see.

Comment: I went and tested your code I dont work with GCP so i setup an account as I thought this cant be the case. On first instance I think GCP needs a lot of work its buggy, I code in AWS and Azure and I thought at times those were bad. Google seems a world of pain. Essentially conclusion is that the api google compute? Its broke that thing does not work well. If your able to move to another solution.. BTW I did test your code got it working. Your code is great but the google api not so much.